# How to use table by with two arguments? R

Tags: r, dataframe, tabular

My dataset is like this

```
df

ID Year  County  APV   sample 
1  2014   A       1      1
1  2015   A       1      1
1  2016   A       0      0
1  2017   A       NA     0
1  2018   A       NA     0
1  2019   A       NA     0

2  2014   B       1      1
2  2015   B       1      1
2  2016   B       1      1
2  2017   B       1      1
2  2018   B       0      0
2  2019   B       NA     0

3  2014   A       1      1
3  2015   A       1      1
3  2016   A       0      0
3  2017   A       NA     0
3  2018   A       NA     0
3  2019   A       NA     0
```

And so on

So I want to tabulate this data.

If I only want to tabulate by year

`datos<-as.data.frame(table(df$APV==0 & df$sample==0, by=df$Year))`

the data set that I obtain looks like this:

```
df1

Var1   by   Freq
FALSE  2014   3
TRUE   2014   0

FALSE  2015   3
TRUE   2015   0

FALSE  2016   1
TRUE   2016   2

.       .     .
.       .     .
.       .     .
```

So false means the still open firms.

How can I tabulate by year **and** County?

APV tells me the first closure of the enterprise, (the 0) so I want to know how many enterprises closed by year and county

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two approaches.

I added `!is.na(APV)` for two reasons: (1) it wasn't clear to me what you expected to happen there; and (2) `table` was actually more robust to `NA` than `xtabs`, so I wanted the two results to be the same. The *premise* of the two approaches are the same, but they do appear to handle `NA`s differently.

### table

You might just need to know that `table` takes an arbitrary number of arguments, so

```r
head(as.data.frame(table(df$Var1, df$Year, df$County)))
#    Var1 Var2 Var3 Freq
# 1 FALSE 2014    A    2
# 2  TRUE 2014    A    0
# 3 FALSE 2015    A    2
# 4  TRUE 2015    A    0
# 5 FALSE 2016    A    0
# 6  TRUE 2016    A    2
```

While the names are lost, it still works.

### xtabs

```r
out <- as.data.frame(
  xtabs(~ Var1 + Year + County,
  data = transform(df, Var1 = (!is.na(APV) & APV == 0 & sample == 0)))
)
head(out)
#    Var1 Year County Freq
# 1 FALSE 2014      A    2
# 2  TRUE 2014      A    0
# 3 FALSE 2015      A    2
# 4  TRUE 2015      A    0
# 5 FALSE 2016      A    0
# 6  TRUE 2016      A    2
```

(I used `transform` for my simplicity.)

### do.call for dynamic columns

```r
out2 <- as.data.frame(
  do.call(table, subset(transform(df, Var1 = (!is.na(APV) & APV == 0 & sample == 0)), 
                        select = c(Var1, Year, County)))
)
```

(same results)

Comment: Yes, it's true, we've got to get rid off NAs. The xtabs method worked pretty well, therefore you got the right answer. But there isn't a way to do it with table? I am very familiar with that function and I'd like to know if there's any way to do it.

Comment: *Yes*. See my edit. `table` takes as many as you want, my `do.call` variant was intended to be dynamic, perhaps overkill for your needs.